# Valgrind in Clion on Apple silicon

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, clion, apple-silicon

I recently switched to a new MacBook and I was using valgrind in clion on my old MacBook.

Valgrind is not supported in clion on the new Apple Silicon. Is there any other tool I can use for memory leak detection?

Comment: Both GCC and Clang have *sanitizers* that can be used. Build with e.g. `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to let the compiler add code and checks to report errors at run-time.

Comment: Using -fsanitize=leak in this case.